# Как сделать секундомер в боте telegram на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, telebot

Всем привет. Нужна помощь! при нажатии кнопки "Начать работу" должно начать отчитываться время "работы" и прекратить по нажатию кнопки "Завершить работу" и вывести сообщение "Вы работали _ секунд".

```
import telebot
import random
import time
from telebot import types
from time import gmtime, strftime

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('sticker.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
 
    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать работу")

    markup.add(item1)
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный чтобы быть подопытным кроликом.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
          
            if message.text == 'Начать работу':

                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Отправить фото?")
                item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Что клеить?")
                item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Отправить GPS")
                item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Завершить работу")
                markup.add(item1, item2,item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично,время пошло!', reply_markup=markup)
                
            

            elif message.text == 'Что клеить?':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ggg')

            elif message.text == 'Завершить работу':

                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать работу")
                markup.add(item1)

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты работал '' секунд', reply_markup=markup)
            
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить')
  
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил, но через костыли. Решил брать время при начале работе и конце и просто их вычитать.

```
import telebot
import random
import time
import datetime
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('AnimatedSticker.tgs', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
 
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать работу")

    markup.add(item1)
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный чтобы быть подопытным кроликом.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
          
            if message.text == 'Начать работу':
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Отправить фото?")
                item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Что клеить?")
                item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Отправить GPS")
                item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Завершить работу")
                markup.add(item1, item2,item3,item4)

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично,время пошло!', reply_markup=markup)
                minu1=datetime.datetime.now()
                global min1
                min1=minu1.strftime("%M")
                
                hou1=datetime.datetime.now()
                global hour1
                hour1=hou1.strftime("%H")
            
            elif message.text == 'Что клеить?':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ggg')

            elif message.text == 'Завершить работу':

                minu2=datetime.datetime.now()
                min2=minu2.strftime("%M")

                hou2=datetime.datetime.now()
                hour2=hou2.strftime("%H")

                min1hour1=int (hour1*60+min1)
                min2hour2=int (hour2*60+min2)
                res1=min2hour2-min1hour1
                
                resh=(res1-res1%60)/60

                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать работу")
                markup.add(item1)

                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ты работал {resh} ч {res1%60} м', reply_markup=markup)
            
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить')
  
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```